# Chrome & Firefox Date function different. (new Date)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, firefox, cross-browser

> new Date

when I use the date function in chrome I get something like this

> Thu Jul 16 2015 20:37:47 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

when I do the same function in firefox I get this

> 2015-07-17T03:29:03.110Z

why are they different? I googled for a bit and search on stack but even the examples they were using to show their problem were comparing two dates of the same format. What I'd really like to know is why are they different now and how can I go about making them the chrome format cross as many browsers as possible?

Thanks

Comment: That’s just the way these two browsers decided to _display_ `Date` objects _in the console_. They are not different for JavaScript.

Comment: I'd like to take your word on that but it doesn't appear to be the case. I'm on Firefox 39 and Chrome 43 (latest). I get the two different strings and it causes me the issue. I am using a timeline js plugin and it detect the date incorrectly on firefox. The new Date function does display differently, perhaps what is being displayed is the variable used. https://gist.github.com/iktuz/3749287 is the plug I am using.

Comment: Anyway I am gonna go tinker some more, If i don't get it working I'll show you some screenshots and code.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with moment.js
Firefox is in fact giving a different date string, and not simply displaying is differently as stated by Xufox.

The function I am going to use is

> moment(new Date()).format("YYYY MMM D H:mm:ss")

but I will change around the .format, just wanted to get the answer here in case others run into the same problem

EDIT!!!!:
Xufox was right. I was a dummy. I had to manually edit some code in my timeline feed to get it going. I needed to use Date.parse on my generic time string, do my editing to the time, then use new Date. Thanks Xufox.